# How we can compere or check input filed type of html element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I am working on jquery and I am trying alert for check div's child field type . I mean check that is input field and having which type . please see my small code :

```
if($('#'+Gid).find("input[type=radio]"))
    alert("radio");
if($('#'+Gid).find("input[type=checkbox]"))
    alert("radio");
if($('#'+Gid).find("select"))
    alert("select");
```

If any field is present in div that can alert for that . Right now that is going in every condition . Please anyone help me for that . Thanks

Comment: `jQuery` object is always evaluated as `true`. Check `.length` property..

Comment: You need to use `.has()` method to check element existence

Comment: What relevant HTML do you have that you can share with us, so that we can show you a practical answer that directly applies to a valid, relevant example.

Comment: Hi Thanks to all guys for quick response , I will try that all :)

Comment: @Rayon : I use this but that is not working if($('#'+Gid).find("input[type=text]").length())
                            alert("text");

Comment: @vibog – `length` is a property not a `method`, so `.length`, not `.length()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an "exists" function for jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check

```js
var Gid = "container";

if($('#'+Gid + " > input[type=radio]").length > 0)
    console.log("Radio");
if($('#'+Gid + " > input[type=checkbox]").length > 0)
    console.log("Checkbox");
if($('#'+Gid + " > select").length > 0)
    console.log("Select");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
<input type="radio" />  
  <input type="checkbox" />  
 <select></select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the field type by following

```
<script>
        function findInputType(formObject) {
          for (i=0; i<formObject.childNodes.length; i++) {
             if (formObject.childNodes[i].tagName == "INPUT") {
                    if (formObject.childNodes[i].type == "checkbox") {
                   alert("This is CheckBox type.")
                }
                if (formObject.childNodes[i].type == "radio") {
                   alert("This is Radio type")
                }
             }   
             if (formObject.childNodes[i].tagName == "SELECT") {
                   alert("This is Select field")
             }
          }
    </script>     

    <script>
        // method to find the input type
        findInputType(document.myform)

    </script>
```

Comment: I accept your answer but can we do it with more optimization that is some lengthy . Please anyone give any solution .

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to find all the types of input elements including select in a div, you can do something like this :

```js
$(function() {
  var elems = new Set(); //for collecting unique elements
  $("#myDiv input").each(function() {
    elems.add($(this).attr("type"));
  });
  if ($("#myDiv select").length > 0) elems.add("select");
  for (let item of elems) console.log(item);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
  <input type="radio" name="rad" />Radio
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="rad" />Checkbox
  <br/>
  <input type="text" />
  <br/>
  <select>
    <option>Select</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Or change your current code to something like this :

```js
$(function() {
  var Gid = "myDiv";
  if ($('#' + Gid + " input[type=radio]").length != 0)
    alert("radio");
  if ($('#' + Gid + " input[type=checkbox]").length != 0)
    alert("checkbox");
  if ($('#' + Gid + " select").length != 0)
    alert("select");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
  <input type="radio" name="rad" />Radio
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="rad" />Checkbox
  <br/>
  <select>
    <option>Select</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach, which should cover most use-cases, is the following:

```
var Gid = "container";

// here we look inside the '#container' element to find all
// elements matching the jQuery ':input' selector expression,
// which includes <select>, <input>, <textarea>,
// and then we iterate over each of the found elements (if
// any):    
$('#' + Gid).find(':input').each(function(){

  // caching the current element for repeated use:
  var el = this,

      // localName is the same as tagName, but in lowerCase,
      // for example 'INPUT' is 'input':
      tag = el.localName,

      // here we see if the current element has a 'type' property,
      // which it does if the tag is equal to 'input'; if it does
      // have a 'type' property we assign a string to tell the
      // user what that 'type' is; otherwise we return an empty
      // string instead (so that the later concatenation will
      // still work):
      hasType = tag === 'input' ? ', of type="' + el.type + '"' : '',

      // a naive check to see if we should say 'an input...' or
      // 'a select...':
      determiner = ['a','e','i','o','u'].indexOf(tag.charAt(0)) > -1 ? 'an' : 'a';
  console.log('This is ' + determiner + ': ' + tag + ' element' + hasType);
});
```

```js
var Gid = "container";

$('#' + Gid).find(':input').each(function() {
  var el = this,
    tag = el.localName,
    hasType = tag === 'input' ? ', of type="' + el.type + '"' : '',
    determiner = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].indexOf(tag.charAt(0)) > -1 ? 'an' : 'a';
  console.log('This is ' + determiner + ': ' + tag + ' element' + hasType);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <input type="radio" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <select></select>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/d6uq0mrg/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).
  - [Conditional (Ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
  - [`Element.localName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/localName).
  - [`String.prototype.charAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt).
- jQuery:

  - [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
  - [`:input` selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector).